# How do I get ID of the user from KeyCloak 3.4.3.Final using IDToken Class

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak 3.4.3.Final.  I am trying to get the ID of the user using getId() method of the class org.keycloak.representations.IDToken in my Java application, when the user is authenticated.  The ID I am referring to is the ID field shown in the screen shot below.  The getId() method does not return this ID value.  I believe the getId() returns the JWS Token value.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: What you would like a want to get the user id? from the IDtoken?

Comment: I am trying to get the user's Id from IDToken after the user is successfully authenticated.  If that is not possible using IDToken, I would like to how I can get the user's id after the user is successfully authenticated?

Comment: I have the solution for this one do you still need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  The getSubject() method was the one I needed.